# How to make table side by side

Tags: react-native, react-native-table-component

I'm new beginner in react-native. Now i am trying to set a table side by side but i am totally confused how could i manage it,

My table is something like this:

[image]

and i want my table like Devices1 & Devices2 will be side by side not like this:

suppose:

[image]

How can i manage the table side by side?